# XmlSerializer Deserialize list only getting the first item

Tags: c#, xml

This is my XML i get from an API:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<response>
<datetime>2015-05-18 11:37:32</datetime>
<count>2</count>
<smsleft>40920</smsleft>
<sms><smsid>535041581</smsid><smsid>535041583</smsid></sms>
</response>
```

This is my class i try to parse it to:

```
[XmlRoot("response")]
public class SMSResponse
{
    [XmlElement("sms")]
    public List<smsid> Sms { get; set; }
}

public class smsid
{
    [XmlElement("smsid")]
    public string SmsID { get; set; }
}
```

Using this code:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SMSResponse));
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(response))
{
   SMSResponse result = (SMSResponse)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

However i only get the first SmsID in the list in my result, not 2 as in the reponse.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've declared `SmsID` as a `string`, so only a single one can be deserialized.  You've declared `Sms` as a list, but only one exists in your input file.

Try:

```
[XmlRoot("response")]
public class SMSResponse
{
    [XmlArray("sms")]
    [XmlArrayItem("smsid")]
    public List<string> SmsID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
[XmlRoot("response")]
public class SMSResponse
{
    [XmlElement("sms")]
    public SMS Sms { get; set; }
}

public class SMS
{
    [XmlElement("smsid")]
    public List<string> SmsID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[XmlRoot("response")]
public class SMSResponse
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "sms")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "smsid", Type = typeof(smsid))]
    public List<smsid> Sms { get; set; }
}

public class smsid
{
    [XmlText]
    public string SmsID { get; set; }
}
```